# Error while Datastage Installation Using Docker container

Tags: datastage

I am doing an POC to create a container of Datastage .
During Installation of Datastage facing error at Requirement checks.
Please find attached error:

FAILED | Ensure that BC(Command line Calculator) is installed on your machine.

This BC is already installed on my machine.

bc --version
bc 1.06.95

Please help to resolve this issue.Thanks

Comment: Are you installing Datastage on your machine or inside your Docker container?
Are you getting this error inside the Docker container?
Is BC installed inside your Docker container?

Comment: I think there are ready-to-use datastage containers that can be downloaded from IBM passport advantage. But I did not try them and it's also depending on your license, I think. I would suggest to get in contact with IBM support and ask for help, since they're for sure keen to sell something. Please let us know how it went...